# input boxes in puzzle grid should update the value from the list

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

I am new to JQuery and trying to solve an issue of updating the input boxes with Jquery call back
I am creating a puzzle grid, I created all grid cells as input boxes, when user types English letters in the cell, I check them in the dictionary and update the input field with map value.
how to use call back function / Ajax to update the input values (with converted) values

below code is not holding the English letters properly

```
    $("input").each(function () {
        var temp = '';
        $(this).on("input", function () {
             alert($(this).val()); 
            $(this).val(my_dict[$(this).val()]);
        });
 
    });
```

Comment: you don't need `.each()` call

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following example.

```js
$(function() {
  var myDict = [
    "Hello",
    "World",
    "FOO",
    "bar"
  ];
  $("input").change(function(evt) {
    var v = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    var i = myDict.findIndex(function(el) {
      return el.toLowerCase() === v;
    });
    if (i !== -1) {
      $(this).val(myDict[i]);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
<input type="text">
```

This uses `.findIndex()` to find the proper index in the Array, and is Case insensitive. Once you know the Index, you can replace the Value with your element from the Array.

For example, if the user enters "hello", when the event is triggered, it will be changed to "Hello".